# How to save Java Project from IntelliJ IDEA to Git repo so it will build on another PC after cloning?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I'm building a simple calculator app from a tutorial/class on Pluralsight (Java Fundamentals class), which starts with a `Main.java` file, and adds a class file later, `MathEquation.java`.

I created a Git repo to track my progress, and uploaded to Github: [JavaFundamentalsClass](https://github.com/LightCC/JavaFundamentalsClass). I used **GitIgnore.IO** to find a [Java IntelliJ **.gitignore** file](https://www.gitignore.io/api/java,intellij), and everything seemed to be working fine on the original PC I was using.

However, after switching over to a different PC, with a fresh install of IDEA, I cloned down the repo from Github, and found that the project would not build and/or run.  I get this error:

> "C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191-1\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar ""
>
> Error: Unable to access jarfile
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I suspect that there is something in the `.gitigore` file that is keeping some of the project, dependency, or build information from being saved in the repo that keeps IDEA from having all the info it needs to build and run the `Main.java` correctly.

Can anyone help?  You should be able to download the project from the repo linked above in it's currently broken state, including the .gitignore file.

---

**Additional Info**

I wiped my repo clean and recloned and I forgot, originally it doesn't even give me the run button (it is grayed out). I had to do a procedure with "Add Configuration" from a search I did for that to show up to get the error above.

Also, I did install java from the OpenJDK, rather than oracle.  I figured with Oracle cutting off commercial development maybe start the switch now as I'm learning, but maybe that's the issue (normal Java on my other PC).

---

**It's working, but...**

First thing - Intellij needs to know where Java is. It appears that if the SDK/JDK is not installed prior to Intellij, you will need to tell it where Java is after installing. Or if you use OpenJDK instead of Oracle Java SDK. You can do that at `View/Open Library Settings`, under **Platform Settings / SDKs** (select the `JDK home path`).

Then, after setting up Java, I am able to get everything working in Intellij IDEA if I find the `Main.java` file, right-click, and choose "Run main.main()". This runs the program okay, and also creates a `Main` configuration in the Run/Debug configuration area, and finally the "Run" button becomes available.

So I can get it working, but if I wipe all the files and clone it fresh from the remote repo, I have to go through running the `Main.java` file directly again to recreate the configuration.

***So, this still doesn't answer my original question. Why doesn't this configuration get saved in the repo? What file is this information saved in? Is there something in the `.gitignore` file that is keeping this information from being saved to the repo?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first part is ensuring Java is setup, and that Intellij IDEA knows where Java is, per the other answers, comments, and addendums to the question.
2. The second part is setting up the run/debug configuration, per the **"It's working but.."** section of the question. This can be created automatically by right-clicking the file that has the main class to be run (usually Main()...), and selecting the **"Run Main.main()"** option (replacing `Main` and `main()` with the file and function which needs to be run)
3. The final piece is that to get the run/debug configurations to save to the repo, you either need to:

   - Share the `workspace.xml` file (i.e. make sure this is not in the `.gitignore` file). However, there is a lot of user-specific stuff in that file, so it should normally be excluded from the repo.
   - Or, edit the configuration and checkmark the "Share" box in the upper right-hand corner (just right of the "Name" field). This will put the configuration into a separate folder inside the `.idea` folder, which should not be excluded from the repo by `.gitignore`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Look like you have a different java version on your second machine.

- First of all, check your java version
- Update the configuration of your project, right now it pointing to java 1.8

https://github.com/LightCC/JavaFundamentalsClass/blob/master/.idea/misc.xml

[image]

[image]

Comment: This was partly right. I needed to show Intellij where Java was, using the "External Libraries" area. This was required after installing Java, whether I used Oracle's Java SDK or OpenJDK. But then I still need to find and run the "main" file directly to get the main "Run" button to become available. This also creates a configuration for "Main". Why doesn't this configuration get stored in the repo?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because of java not installed on the other PC you were trying. If it is installed just check whether the path mentioned has java executable file.

Comment: @LightCC do you have java installed on other PC? I see the issue is clearly not with IDE or .gitignore file.

Comment: I have the `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191-1` OpenJDK installed. Maybe this is the issue, but it is showing up in the project under the "External Libraries" area.

Comment: @LightCC can you try out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html , just try creating simple hello world program and try to run it, once done you can import the cloned project to IDE and run it.

Comment: Once I point Intellij to Java, then I can build, but I have to find the file with the Main function and directly run it by right-clicking and selecting run. After I do that once, it adds a configuration for "Main" and the normal run button comes available. But if I delete all the files and reclone the repo, I'm back to the same situation - why doesn't that configuration for Main save to the repo?